# Why is it that the product $(a-x)(b-x) \cdots(y-x)(z-x)$ simplifies to $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

I came across this trick question, and I don't understand the solution to the puzzle. We are asked to simplify the product
$$(a-x)(b-x) \cdots(y-x)(z-x),\tag{$*$}$$
and the answer is apparently supposed to be $0$.

I have no idea how this can be, and how one can simplify the above expression. Can someone explain to me why the product $(*)$
simplifies to $0$?

Comment: It has a  factor $x-x$

Answer (score 3):

Its a puzzle and a trick question and not a legitimate math question.

We are tricked into think that there is a variable we call $x$ and a sequence of constants $a,b,c,....,y,z$ and we need to find the product of $(a-x)(b-x)... (y-x)(z-x)$ and that is hard.  But if we use the naming conventions of letters then one of our constants will be $x$ and our variable, which we intuitively think of as a different animal altogether, is actually a constant.  So one of our terms is $(x-x)=0$ and the product is $0$.

But this is nonsense.

Every letter is a variable and we have no idea what they represent so we do not know what values they will be so we can not use $....$ to represent going from $a$ to $b$ to $c$ etc so we can't know that the unnamed terms are $(c-x), (d-x),(e-x)$ etc.  This is simply badly written math.

If we legitimately wanted to do something like this we'd have to index the variables in some way perhaps like $(a_1 -x)(a_2 - x) ..... (a_{26} - x)$ with it understood there is a known or calculable sequence of variable $a_1, a_2, a_3....$.

If we wrote this as $(a_1 - a_{24})(a_2-a_{24})(a_3 - a_{24}).... (a_{25} - a_{24})(a_{26} - a_{24})$ it should be obvious that one of the terms is $(a_{24}-a_{24}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As lab bhattacharjee pointed out (assuming the implied pattern is to be followed), one of the terms in that expression (namely, the term before the third shown term) is $x-x$, which is of course equal to $0$ and causes the whole expression to be equal to $0$ as well.